# Onfocus event not triggered in HTML <select> box on Android

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, android-browser

I want to listen for the `onfocus`-event of an HTML `<select>` dropdown box. The `onfocus` event is triggered in every browser except in the native Android browser (tested using Android 1.6 and Android 2.3.3).

I created the following code to demonstrate my issue:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select onfocus='$("#info").html("you got the focus!")'>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
            <span id="info">No focus currently...</span>
        </form>            
    </body>
</html>
```

​
You can also [see this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/).

As said, this is working in every browser (tested using current versions of Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer), but not in the native Android browser. It is also working on mobile Safari on iPhone 3GS. Anyway, the `onfocus` event works on `<input>` elements on all browsers, also on Android native browser.

How can I make the `onfocus` event working on `<select>` elements in the Android browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jQuery code](http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/16/) does the trick for me now on Android devices

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").bind('mouseenter', function(event) {
      $(this).focus();
    });
    $("#select").bind('mouseleave', function(event) {
      $(this).blur();
    });
});​
```

Basically, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are triggered on Android devices. I found this out by [logging all events](http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/12/) which are triggered on the `select` element.

The good thing is, that I still can use the `onfocus` event in my `select` element. The disadvantage is that this code must only be executed on Android devices.

Answer (score 3):

w4rumy's answer worked perfectly for me, thank you. But to counter w4rumy's "disadvantage" with his code, I improved on it a bit.

To check the device, simply do:

```
 var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android");

    if (isAndroid > -1) {
        alert("Android!");
        $("select").bind('mouseenter', function (event) {
            $(this).focus();
        });
        $("select").bind('mouseleave', function (event) {
            $(this).blur();
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("iPhone!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a few similar problems with blackberry...

My work around was the following

```
<select onfocusin='DO SOMETHING' onfocusout="DO SOMETHING">
```

That should work if it doesnt why not try

```
$('#SELECTID').focus(function(){
//code to do on focus here
});
```

WORKING:

http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/4/

This also works:
http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/6/

Its the jQuery code within your on focus causeing the issues.

Hope this helps

Comment: [I tried it using onfocusin](http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/1/), but that did not work. [Also using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/esbYy/3/) for the onfocus event does not work on Android browser.

Comment: By the looks if it , its because of andorids custom way of showing selects, only thing i can recommend is trying the following, onblur,onfocusin,onfocusout,onchange and see what ones work and building your code around it as i cant seem to find a work around hope i helped though

Comment: Try putting the jqueyr code within a function and calling that on focusin or out or onfoucs

Comment: It is working on my desktop browser, but not on my Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.3.3. I also played around with onclick (did not work) and ontouchstart (which works sometimes, also not acceptable). Did you try it on an Android device?

Comment: Yes tried it on my sensation my jsfiddle /6 one works perfect

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy S it is not working, no alerts popping up. I tried it on a HTC Legend (Android 2.2) and I only get the message from the onchange event, not the alert from the onfocus event. Do you get this, too? I want to listen for the onfocus event, not for the onchange.

Comment: I get message for on foucs fine on the sensation